# Mysql not returning a select query by specific number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and calling data from a table -

```
    $this->connection->select('*');
    $this->connection->from($this->database);

    if(is_numeric($item))
    {
        $this->connection->where('id',$item);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->connection->or_like('name',$item);
    }

    $this->connection->limit(50, 0);

    $query = $this->connection->get();

    die(print_r($query->result_array())." die");
```

When I input Item as any ID that is available in the database it correctly returns the array. But when I use 4147 (which is also present in the database, it doesn't print it.). Also when using $item as a string, it doesn't return certain words which some in the 'name' field do contain.

Comment: Update - Error log shows results, it seems $query->result_array() won't hold the values in an array, or return or print normally with print_r for those particular queries for some reason. Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `or_like()` incorrectly, as it doesn't have a leading 1st where statement. your code produces something like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE OR name LIKE '%abc%'`, which troughs an error.

the correct way is to use:

```
else
{
    $this->connection->like('name',$item);
    // now you can start using or
    $this->connection->or_like('address',$anotheritem);

}
```

Comment: Hi, no i logged the output through error_log it shows - `name  LIKE '%apple%'`, the OR is only added if one makes a second call with or_like. This return was successful. but with words such as `sword` etc there is no output... inspite of there being many rows containing such in the db.

Comment: try $this->connection->like('name',''.$item.'');

Comment: Thanks but no change in result... I'm on OSX yosemite if that makes any difference, just thought i'd mention.